# Image found on src attribute but not loaded

Tags: html, css, laravel-mix, tailwind-css

I'm really new on web development and I want to load an image. The image is found but not loaded for some reason.
This is what I mean when I say that the image is found:
[image]

This is part of my code (Stack Overflow is saying it is too big for the post):

```
<div class="flex flex-col flex-grow pt-4 pb-4 overflow-y-auto bg-white border-r border-gray-200">
    <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 px-4">
        <img class="w-auto h-8" src="./exchange/resources/assets/img/logo/angel-lg.png" alt="Angel Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-grow flex-shrink-0 mt-4">
...
```

And here's what's shown up on the screen:
[image]

I'm using Laravel Mix on this project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: If it's not loaded, than it's not been found. Check your [**Browser Inspector**](https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549) for exact details as to why. I suspect the image doesn't reside in the directory specified in the `<img>` tag

Comment: "The image is found" do you mean that you retrieved the image from somewhere else on the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the image' relative path (./) is the public folder. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Basically what's going on here is you have the wrong path for your image.

```
<img class="w-auto h-8" src="./exchange/resources/assets/img/logo/angel-lg.png" alt="Angel Logo"> <!-- src/path is wrong -->
```

What's displaying on the screen is the alt text, "Angel Logo", which means that the picture was not indeed found.
Can you provide the path of the image you are trying to display? (Right click on the image on your desktop and select "Copy path")

Comment: Ah, now I get that the alt text is displayed, sorry...
C:\laragon\www\exchange\resources\assets\img\logo\angel-lg.png
Here's the full image's path!

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but the Request URL in the network tab is: http://exchange.test/www/exchange/resources/assets/img/logo/angel-lg.png

Comment: @FernandoRodriguesCoelho what is the path of this HTML file?